# Refresh Frameset

Tags: html, refresh, frameset

I have a site with a frame:

```
<frameset cols="69%,31%">
  <frame src="main.php" />
  <frame src="result.html" />
</frameset>
```

Its looks like this:

```
------------|-----------
            |
search      | result1
            | result2
            | result3
            |
            |
            |
            |
------------|---------
```

Here is how it workrs (it is much more complex)

Main.php (left frame) uses a search (like a search engine) result.html (right frame) , only reads what main.php founds, so:

What I want to do is refresh result.html from main.php. How can I do this???

NOTE: I do not want to autorefresh result.html (right frame) with AJAX timer or something. The refresh must be triggered by main.php (left frame)

Comment: mm something like onclick load "http://yoursite.com?=searchparams"? You could set the target to the id of the frame if its applicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a JavaScript function into the page that holds the two frames you can accomplish this.

In the parent page:

```
refreshResults = function () {
    resultFrame.location.reload();
}
```

and then call it from main.php like this:

```
parent.refreshResults ();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

first, you need to assign "name" attribute in your frame like:

> <frameset cols="69%,31%">
>   <frame src="main.php" />
>   <frame src="result.html" />
>   </frameset>

In main.php

> <script> function btn_reset() {
>     parent.result.location.reload(); }
>    </script>
>
> <input type="button" value="Click"
>   onclick="btn_reset()">